# Can a stepper motor flyback diode discharge a coil when connected in serial to the coil and opposite to the current?

Tags: transistors, diodes, inductor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

On a circuit taken from this page http://www.opend.co.za/tutorials/steptut1.htm

The last circuit shows two diodes positioned in reverse polarity to the current.

It is supposed to protect against the inductive kickback of each coil when its driving transistor is turned off.

But when one transistor is closed and the diode is not connected in parallel to the coil (as most flyback diodes I've seen) how can a closed circuit be formed between the two sides of the coil to discharge it?

[image]

Comment: The answer is on the website: D2 is protecting Q1.

Comment: @Huisman Yes, i read is before posting, but i still don't understand how can a closed circuit be formed between the two sides of the coil to discharge it

Comment: You CANNOT put the diode in series with the coil. The schematic is correct and the closed circuit INCLUDES the power supply.

Comment: @JackCreasey , if coil A is energized when  Q1 is open, then when it's closed, coil A would be in series with the diode D1, still energized by the magnetic field, in that case where would that current go  if the diode is connected in such a way ?

Comment: @soundslikefiziks If coil A is energized then Q1 is ON ...it cannot be energized otherwise. When Q1 is turned OFF, the back EMF is reflected on BOTH D1 and D2 (the two coils are effectively a transformer and usually bifilar wound). So as the voltage across D1 rises to VCC (and beyond) D1 will not conduct …..but the voltage across D2 will drop (transformer action) and drive the cathode of D2 below Gnd where it will conduct. Coil B and the diode are in series only for the back EMF with the circuit completed by the power supply (usually with large output capacitance.

Comment: @JackCreasey so for example if  the right side of coil A would be -12v with respect to ground, the ground would become the (+) with respect to coil A and then current would flow from ground through the D2 , through coil B an eventually completely de-energizing coil A even though only one side of it is connected ? if so, what about Q1, ? in that case, voltage across it's base-emitter junction should turn it on, thus providing a path through Q1-D2-coil B for  coil A to discharge.

Comment: @soundslikefiziks NO.....if you had Q1 ON and Q2 OFF, then turned Q1 OFF the energy (stored in the magnetic material via coil A) would be dissipated in coil B via D2. The RHS of coil A and the LHS of coil B is ALWAYS at +12V since it's directly connected to the supply ...it can never be anything different. The backEMFs produced will never turn on either Q1 or Q2. When you turn off Q1 the cathode of D2 (coil B RHS) will develop MORE than -12V so causing the diode to conduct. D2 therefore clamps the RHS of coil B to about -1V. The current (that originally flowed in coil A now flows in coil B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question really depends on what type of stepping motor you are using.
In this case from the web link you provided they are discussing a unipolar stepping motor where the phase coils are bifilar wound and act very much as a transformer.

Here is a schematic with the simulation so you can see the waveforms.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZnUgX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Waveform]

Notice that the back EMF is clipped by the diode on the OPPOSITE transistor to the one just turned off. So D2 clips the back EMF caused by Q1 turning off and D1 clips the back EMF when Q2 turns off.

The website is a very poor tutorial since no attempt is made to clarify the differences between stepper motor configurations. The technique for example could not be applied to a 2 phase single winding stepper motor. It uniquely applies to a dual wound (or center tapped) winding configuration driven as a unipolar stepper.

Comment: Yup...the circuit only applies to 4-phase step motors with center-tapped windings.

Comment: Phases A and C are 100% coupled.  Note the dot convention!

Comment: When phase A shuts off, the current in phase C jumps to the same value....except negative!  Eventually, the current in phase C goes positive.  On the next step, this is repeated except with phases B and D.

Comment: @JackCreasey i tried to simulate this circuit on an online simulator  http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html  , because it shows a live simulation of the current flow. i used two coils instead of a transformer, and when Q1 is turned off, current flows from ground through D1 and Coil 1 , and not D2. i then removed Q2 L2(the 2nd coil) and D2 from the circuit and the same thing happened. when Q1 is turned off, current flows through D1 , from ground to 12v. this is the opposite from what i know about inductors and  diodes .. current flowing from low to high ?

Comment: @soundslikefiziks  You cannot use two independent coils as falstad know nothing about the coupling coefficients.

Comment: @JackCreasey it worked the same with one coil and one diode and one transistor , when the diode is connected in parallel with the transistor, when the transistor shuts down, current flows from ground to the +12v, through the diode and the coil. (i also saw this configuration as a snubber circuit on this site)

Comment: @soundslikefiziks Sorry, it does not work that way. Current cannot flow from ground through the coil to the supply. When you turn off the transistor the collector goes positive and the diode does not conduct.